# How to test UTF-8 strings in Java

Tags: java, testing, web-applications, utf-8

I have to test a web app and its API for UTF-8 strings.

Webapp has a text field and its API has corresponding getter method, I have to make sure UTF-8 will work, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put in characters outside of the standard ASCII set - i.e. anything above 127 or 255 in the character levels and see that they come out the other end of the API correctly.

Here is a character map generator:

http://dev.networkerror.org/utf8/

Comment: @aperkins: +1 for the shiny tool :)

Comment: Thanks aperkins! this is really good. I have tested string "şĀýßŗ" in webapp, it stores as it is, but API getter method shows as 
"??ýß?" is something wrong in the API getter method?

Comment: @goutham: Not totally sure - it would depend on a number of things.  Does the page send back information using utf-8 encoding, or a different one?  Is the page response being decoded with the proper encoding?  What language was the library written in?  There are a number of possibilities there.

Answer (score 1):

aperkins gave a good suggestion.
Note that depending on your IDE, you may need to set the your editor to UTF-8 and set the java compiler option `-encoding utf-8`